# HTML Email CSS: Centering the table and table content, most supported solution

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm preparing the email html file for mailing. I'm using the table, tr, td tags. The whole content of my html so far is placed within a table, including another small table within one of the cells (see pictures below). I would like the whole table to display always in the center. I would also like the small table to display in the middle of the cell. The width of outer table it fixed.
I tried putting into CSS:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

and

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

, all of which I have found in here. The preview looks fine with either, the preview after uploading the file into mass mailing system works ok as well. But after sending, the centering does not display at all (the inner table also doesn't display at all in Gmail, only content of it). So I'm looking for the most common, most widely used html property, which would most likely display the table in the middle in every browser/mail client. OR, for the advice regarding the possible wrong usage of class properties.

My whole  section:

```
<style>
table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Verdana, sant-serif;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}

.main {
    width:1000px;
    border: 5px solid #114889;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.inside {
  width: 500px; 
  border: 1px dotted #0000CC;
  background-color: #CCE5FF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
    
</style>
```

I am not a pro with the topic so I apologize for the use of wrong terminology.

Edit:
Display in Outlook. All is well but the left alignment:
[image]

Display in Gmail. No tables whatsoever:
[image]

Comment: Did you try it using ````flex-box````? e.g. ````display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;```` Use ````align-items```` for vertical alignment and ````justify-content```` for vertical alignment.

Comment: @michaelT flex unfortunatly doesn't work for mail css :/

Comment: I think you should specify it's for mails in the title. CSS for emails is different enough, it has its rules and its experts

Comment: @CristianTraìna oh I didn't know that. Thank you, I edited the title

Comment: Very weird that Gmail is not displaying the table at all - or perhaps not the border? Can you show the HTML code for that part?

Comment: @Nathan, the whole code is here: www.jsfiddle.net/enter8810/1oeL7vk6

The part in question (before inline css) looked like this: 
`<tr> <td>Participants: <table class="inside"> <tr> <th class="inside">Person 1</th> <th class="inside">Person 4</th>  </tr><tr> <td class="inside">Person 2</td> <td class="inside">Person 5</td>  </tr> <tr> <td class="inside">Person 3</td> <td class="inside">Person 4</td> </tr></table></td></tr>` (I apologize if it's too difficult to read), but it seems that inlining CSS helps! Can I further adjust this code for normal web html usage?

Answer (score 4):

Outlook only works with tables, so you're right to approach it from that angle. However, some Gmail environments do not even look at embedded CSS (CSS within `<head>` section). You'll need to 'inline' the CSS (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/tools/css-inliner/).

To center a table in Outlook, use the attribute align on the `<table>` element like so: `<table width="300" align="center"...>`. You may also need to wrap it all with `<center>...</center>`, even though that tag is deprecated (yes, email is that old!).

You'll find in general Outlook will support the attributes - e.g. for border colours, `<td bgcolor="#abcdef"...>` - whereas others will support the inline style, e.g. `<td style="background-color:#abcdef"...>`. You should use both, and not rely on embedded CSS.

I can update more specifically if you need, after posting the affected HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! I went back to the inline css. First, I added `align:center;` to both of my class descriptions. I also added `<center>...</center>` tags before and after each `<table>` element. Then I used the inliner tool. Works great in both Outlook, Gmail! At first try (with only inlining css but without adding centering tools) graphic did not work (surprisingly), but when I applied all your suggestions it does...? Anyway, ending result is great, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
.parentTable {
  position: relative;
}

.childTable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: thank you. Do I add those properties to the .main and .inside classes (as per my code) instead of `margin: 0px auto;` and leave the rest of the properties intact? When I did it like that, the file went crazy. Or should I add those classes separately and then point to them in certain way within the code? I'm not really well versed with classes yet,

Comment: No issues. I think you can take parentTable css properties to your main class and childTable css to inside class. just try it.

Comment: This is not right, not for email. They have very limited subset of CSS they support

Comment: @KRISHJACKMAN, thank you for taking the time! Unfortunately it doesn't work for my email indeed :(